# Laravel send all types of exceptions as JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, exception

I'm building my app via Laravel 5.2 as an API and I need all of the types of the exceptions to be as json, no matter whats the error code.

I did something like this:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Exception $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return response([
        'success' => false,
        'error' => [
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ],
    ], $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e)->getStatusCode());
}
```

and it did quite much the trick, but clearly that's not good enough because if I get a 404 error, the `$e->getMessage` is empty.

**Example of 404 Error response:**

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": ""
  }
}
```

What's the best way to respond the exceptions as json?

Comment: Could prefix the message with what the status means. Check http://angelo.mandato.com/2008/12/31/php-function-http-status-code-value-as-string/ for a simple function that does that.

Comment: those errors just return the meaning of the error, but not the error itself.

Comment: If you set a request header of `Accept` with the value `application/json` then Laravel will send all responses in JSON. This is pretty easy to do in something like Postman while you're testing your API but it's obviously an extra thing to tell your users to do when they consume your API. If you use Lumen to build your API, it will respond with JSON no matter what.

Comment: The error itself is returned by the error code. That function translates the error code to human readable text. The error message is optionally added where required. A 404 error is self-explanatory and doesn't really require a message (or should not really require a message).

Comment: @Joseph, When I tried to add this header in POSTMAN, it still sent me an HTML error. and I'm working with laravel.

Comment: @apokryfos, a 404 Error text can be for example for no results for X model.

Comment: I don't know why it's returning HTML when you're setting the header I mentioned. But if it's returning a proper 404 then do you really need to parse the response body? You or whoever is consuming the API can handle a 404 correctly regardless of whether it's HTML or JSON.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but I don't see why `$e->getMessage()` being empty is a problem .

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return response(json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'error' => [
                'code' => $e->getCode(),
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ],
        ]), $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e)->getStatusCode())
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```